# Is it fungus or something else attacking my Areca Plant?

Tags: houseplants, soil, areca-palm

[image: White and brown residue visible on trunk]
[image: White residue on trunk]
[image: New Leafs are brown]

I wonder what's attacking my Areca plant, recently she definetly struggles with growing healthy and large leafs, every new leaf is small, brownish, and dried, as seen on pic 3. I've inspected her real close with magnifying glass, wasn't able to find any insects on the leafs. White spots in the soil is perlite.

I have air humidifier set on 60%, plant is watered using 7 days old brita-filtered water.